# JAVA: Stripe webhook error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I have been trying to set a webhook for the `person.updated` API from Stripe. I am trying a test webhook where I send a String in the method, like this:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Webhook controller")
    @PostMapping("/accountUpdate")
    public void handle(@RequestBody String event1, Response response, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
}
```

and then in my `Webhook.constructEvent`, I am passing that String event1 as follows:

```
 try {
            event = Webhook.constructEvent(
                    event1, sigHeader, endpointSecret
            );
     }
```

But I am getting an error saying: `No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload`

I have tried to parse the String event1 (Which is the request body) into Json and it doesn't work. Passing the Request object instead of String didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your end point Secret which you are providing in your code is incorrect or not matching to your person.update webhook's secret. End point secret goes like this.

"secret": "whsec_gaasdfkalkkklasew**********"

Comment: Thanks! I changed and made sure the secret was as in my webhook and it actually worked when passed as a String.